# Switch Statement In Loop Logging Wrong Value

Tags: javascript, loops, switch-statement

I have a switch statement that looks like this:

```
subCatTDs = 8;

switch(subCatTDs){
    case 3:
        //Do some code
    case 2:
        //Do some code
    case 8:
        console.log(subCatTDs);
}
```

I simplified this down from the rest of the code to try and get the issue that's happening. `subCatTDs` does get set to different values (and is part of a bigger loop) but you would think in this case that I'm explicitly declaring it's values right before the switch statement and the console is printing out (as I was saying, it's in a loop):

```
3
8
```

Why would it ever say '3' when I'm setting the value directly before the statement?

### EDIT

Here is more of the code. It may not make too much sense with the grander scheme but it may help (it's a pretty complex plugin so it'll be hard to include everything here; let me know if you need clarification on anything):

```
for(i = 0; i < numberTRs; i++){
    var subCatValue = i + 1;
    var subCatRow = $('.subCatTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + subCatValue + ')');
    var subCatTDs = subCatRow.find('> td').length;

    //This used to be 5 now it's 4?
    switch(subCatTDs){
        case 3:
            //Subcat Title
            for(j = 0; j < subCatTDs; j++){
                    switch(j){
                    case 0:
                    case 2:
                        var nthChild = j + 1;
                        var subCatElement = $('.subCatTable tr:nth-child(' + subCatValue + ') td:nth-child(' + nthChild + ')');
                        var subCatTitle = subCatElement.html();
                        $('div#subcat-' + rowCounter + '-' + subCatCounter).append('<div class="subCatTitle">' + subCatTitle + '</div>');
                        subCatCounter++;
                        if(subCatCounter>subCatPerRow){
                            subCatCounter = 1;
                        }
                    }
            }
        case 2:
            //First time through

            //Second time through
            if(case2==true){
                        rowCounter++;
                        case2 = false;
                        continue;
            }

            case2 = true;

        case 8:
            console.log(subCatValue);
            for(j = 0; j < subCatTDs; j++){
                        switch(j){
                            case 0:
                            case 5:
                                        //Get the appropriate nth-child
                            var nthChild = j + 1;
                            var subCatElement = $('.subCatTable tr:nth-child(' + subCatValue + ') td:nth-child(' + nthChild + ')');
                            var subCatImage = subCatElement.html();
                                            $('div#subcat-' + rowCounter + '-' + subCatCounter).append('<div class="subCatImage">' + subCatTitle + '</div>');
                                            subCatCounter++;
                        if(subCatCounter>subCatPerRow){
                                                subCatCounter = 1;
                            }

                            case 3:
                            case 8:
                        var subCatDescrip = subCatElement.html();
                        $('div#subcat-' + rowCounter + '-' + subCatCounter).append('<div class="subCatImage">' + subCatDescrip + '</div>');
                        subCatCounter++;
                        if(subCatCounter>subCatPerRow){
                                                subCatCounter = 1;
                            }
                 }
            }               
        }
    }
```

The formatting on the editor is not working well at all. Everything is all out of alignment but I think I got it close. Not sure if this is making sense but you see that I reset the subCatTDs every time it loops through on the for loop. It should never print out '3' since I used console.log() only after checking the case for `8` but for some reason it does.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: need `break;` after each case

Comment: Wouldn't it just get reassigned on every loop though? I guess I'm not understanding why it would do that. Why would it print '3' if it's only suppose to run if the case is '8'?

Comment: Your simplified code example works as is, even though @bencripps is correct that you probably need breaks after each case. Try it in jsfiddle and you will get the correct output. You must have left out something critical when you "simplified". We're brave, show us the rest ;)

Comment: @bitfiddler, just updated it. You'll see that I'm looping through table data...

Comment: @bencripps is right. You need a break statrement at the end of each case or it processing will "fall through" to the next case all the way to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a break statement at the end of each case or processing will "fall through" to the next case all the way to the end. The print in case 8 will always execute.